# Creating the same excel graphs on multiple excel files with similar datasets using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple excel files in a folder with large datasets with 1 sheet. All files are formatted and organized the same/ in a consistent manner. I currently have figured out how I can cycle through all these files and apply a delimiting macro on all of them. I also have a macro that can create the graph I want on an indivdual file. I canot get the 2 macros to combine successfully where I apply the same graph macro on all the files with 1 click.

```
'Simple Graph Macro that works if run on an individual excel file 

Sub ChartMake()

Dim embeddedchart As Shape

Set embeddedchart = Sheets(1).Shapes.AddChart
embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("$A:$B,$E:$E,$H:$H")
embeddedchart.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
embeddedchart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Forward _ :=0, Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=0, DisplayRSquared:=0, Name:= _ "Linear ( Channel 3  Measured value  pH)"
End Sub
```

The next chooses directory and cycles open/closes all files and saves changes.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()

Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook
'Select folder in which all files are stored
fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.Path
If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
  folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If    

'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = False

'Search for all files in folder 
fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.*")
Do While fileName <> ""
    'Update status bar to indicate progress
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName 
  
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)
    Set wb = Workbooks(fileName)
    wb.Activate
    wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Select               
               
    'Module1.split_text Delimiting macro, works
    'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name Just to make sure the current opened worksheet is the active sheet
     Module3.ChartMake ' I either get a 255 error, but if I reduce the range, nothing comes up
  
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True 
    Debug.Print "Processed " & amp; folderName & amp; "\" & amp; fileName
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
eApp.Quit
Set eApp = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is `module3` coming from? Do you not just want to call `ChartMake`?

Comment: ChartMake is in module 3 and RunOnAllFilesInFolder() is in module 2. Both are saved on the same excel spreadsheet acting as the control spreadsheet. This way its just easier for me to test indivdual subs on a excel document.

Comment: ChartMake is listed at the top of my OP. It creates a chart. It runs, but always gets stuck whenit reads the range. Either it gives me a 255 limit error, or nothing gets run. If i were to call it individually from an excel document, it works just fine.

Comment: Any chance another workbook becomes active? Try passing the `wb` variable through, qualify the range in `ChartMake()` and see if that works. (e.g. `Module3.ChartMake wb`)